# Pandas merge two dataframes horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I am dealing with a problem like this:

```py
mydata_old
|  x  |  y   |
|-----|------|
| 1   | 10   |
| 2   | 15   |
| 3   | 12   |
| 4   | 21   |

mydata_new
|  x  |  y   |
|-----|------|
| 4   | 20   |
| 5   | 25   |
| 6   | 30   |
```

I would like to combine both tables to get:

```py
mydata
|  x  |  y   |
|-----|------|
| 1   | 10   |
| 2   | 15   |
| 3   | 12   |
| 4   | 20   | # x = 4 does not show up twice
| 5   | 25   |
| 6   | 30   |
```

I tried with `pandas.merge`, but I cannot get the desired result.

```py
mydata = pd.merge(mydata_new, mydata_old, how="left")
```

Comment: `pd.concat([mydata_old, mydata_new])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with an outer join (i.e., keep the index from both dataframes). You can achieve this using `pd.merge(mydata_new, mydata_old, how='outer')` and then keep the newest data available.

However, this could be more straight forward with `pandas.concat`.

Here, I am concatenating both dataframes. Note that I exclude rows from `mydata_old` if `x` appears in `mydata_new`. This way you can keep the newest data when it's available in both dataframes (old and new).

```py
# Concat frames and if data is available in both, keep data from mydata_new
mydata = pd.concat(
    [
        mydata_old.loc[~mydata_old['x'].isin(mydata_new['x'])],
        mydata_new
    ],
    axis=0)
```

This will print the following:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 5 | 25 |
| 6 | 30 |